# min value of float in java is positive why?

Tags: java

when we use MIN_VALUE function on either of primitive types in java it give us minimum value possible for that type.
BUT
in case of float and double it returned minimum positive value though float and double can have negative values also.

Answer (score 40):

[MIN_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#MIN_VALUE) tells you how precise a float can get, but not the mathematical minimum it can represent. They should have named it better...

Negative of [MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#MAX_VALUE) is the mathematical minimum value for floats(same goes for double).

The reason you can assume this has to do with how numbers are represented in binary:

Java float and doubles use sign bit to represent negative/positive values as opposed to two's complement representation for integers. This means it's positive and negative value have the same magnitude, ie. -(positive max) = negative max. Therefore you don't need to define an actual mathematical minimum constant for floats because you can just use the positive max constant to figure out the what the negative bound is. For integers, you need 2 different constants defining max/min because of the way they represented in binary, i.e. -max != min.

For more info http://people.uncw.edu/tompkinsj/133/numbers/Reals.htm

Comment: This does not explain the inconsistent naming, which is the real point of the question.

Comment: Good point, that is pretty counter-intuitive... I guess they should have named it PRECISION or something...edited my answer

Answer (score 24):

`MIN_VALUE` should be named `EPSILON` it's the smallest postive value a float can represent.

Because a float uses the sign-magnitude encoding, the lowest value a float can represent is `-MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: However, it wasn't. And you could argue that calling it epsilon would be go against mathematical convention. In numerical analysis terms, epsilon is typically the difference between a pair of consecutive floating point numbers.  That varies across the range of the type.

Comment: @StephenC: but this is a computer science convention, not a methematical one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: I think you just proved my point!  The page you linked to says that *machine epsilon* for a 64 bit floating point is 2^−53 ≈ 1.11e-16.  But the javadoc says that `Double.MIN_VALUE` is 2^-1074.

Comment: @StephenC: yes, the machine epsilon is invariant of the exponent.

Answer (score 4):

A possible explanation could be that Java just used the same naming convention as C++, which again inherited the names from C.

Java was influenced by C++, which shares the same confusing naming pattern. In C++, the analogy of `Float.MIN_VALUE` is [`std::numeric_limits<T>::min()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/), which is defined as:

> Minimum finite value.
>   For floating types with denormalization (variable number of exponent bits): minimum positive normalized value.

In C++ that is a potential source of bugs in template code, so later in C++11, they added `std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest()`, which is defined as:

> Minimum finite value. (since C++11)
>   For integral types: the same as min().
>   For floating-point types: implementation-dependent; generally, the negative of max().

But C++ was not the first language. It all goes back to C, which defines [FLT_MIN](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/float.html#FLT_MIN) the minimal floating point value.

So, why did C choose to define the minimums of floating point numbers and integers inconsistently?

Not sure, but it could have to do with symmetry  (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7974042/783510)). For floats, you can use [`-FLT_MAX`](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/float.html#FLT_MAX) (or `-Float.MAX_VALUE`). For integers, negating the maximum value is not portable. In fact, it is generally wrong on all modern architectures (where `-INT_MAX == INT_MIN + 1` should hold).

Answer (score 3):

> min value of float in java is positive why?

Why they chose to name the constants like that is unanswerable (by us) because nobody on SO was in the room when the decision was made.

Besides, knowing the answer to the question is not going to help, because the values of `Float.MIN_VALUE` and `Double.MIN_VALUE`  won't be changed, no matter how "wrong" they might be.  (It would break any existing code that uses these constants, and the Java designers only do that when there is no other viable alternative.  Leaving it alone is clearly a viable alternative.)

I suppose, the answer (i.e. the real reason for the decision) *might* be relevant to people developing brand new programming languages.  However, they are going to have to make up their own minds anyway.  FWIW, I wouldn't have designed it this way, but that's not relevant.

Comment: +1 for noting that the question requires impossible to procure hearsay.

Comment: you really can't tell that nobody here was in the room when the decision was made :) (not me anyways)

Comment: In this context ... "by us" means by people who frequent StackOverflow and answer questions.  I know there are some senior Sun / Oracle Java team members who answer questions here.  But I suspect that the decisions we are talking about here *predate* their involvement.  We are talking about decisions made *before* the release of Java 1.0.   So ... I am pretty sure that nobody on SO is correct.

Comment: And even if the people who made the decisions were here to give us an answer, I doubt that they would *remember* the reasons from nearly 30 years ago.