# Float.parseFloat for negative number out of range returns 0.0

Tags: java, floating-point

How do we check the negative number is out of range for float variable in Java?

If I use Float.parseFloat("1.4E-46"), it returns 0.0 instead of negative infinite. In the case of positive bigger number, it returns infinite.

The below code works for positive number, am looking something similar for negative number.

```
    Float f = Float.valueOf(Float.parseFloat(input));

    if (f.floatValue() > Float.MAX_VALUE) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The reverse is the theoretical `MIN_VALUE`, that is negative of the `MAX_VALUE`
`

Comment: possible duplicate of [min value of float in java is positive why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746850/min-value-of-float-in-java-is-positive-why)

Comment: `1.4E-46` is positive, not negative. It's a really small number.

Comment: Ok. how it should be checked for very small number and it can't be hold under float variable. I believe the min and max value for float are 1.4E-45 & 3.4028235E38

Answer (score 6):

> If I use Float.parseFloat("1.4E-46"), it returns 0.0 instead of negative infinite. In the case of positive bigger number, it returns infinite.

The number `1.4E-46` is **not a negative number**. It is a **very small** positive number.

The opposite of `1.4E+46` is `-1.4E+46`. So if you do `Float.valueOf("-1.4E+46")` you will get `-Infinity`.

Comment: thanks for this. Can you please tell me how to check the value is very small positive value & it's not in float limit? does Float Wrapper class have any method to check for this?

Comment: If you try to do `Float.valueOf()` on a positive number and the result is `0.0`, it means that the number is too small to be represented by a `float` other than `0.0`.

Answer (score 4):

That is not a negative number; it is an extremely small positive number.  This is "computerized" scientific notation.  `1.4E-46` is equivalent to 1.4 x 10<sup>-46</sup>.

The `Float.parseFloat` method parses the number the same as `Float.valueOf(String)`, whose [javadocs state](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-):

> if the exact value of s is small enough in magnitude (less than or equal to MIN_VALUE/2), rounding to float will result in a zero.

Java's parsing method determined that the value is less than `Float.MIN_VALUE / 2`, so it returned a `0.0`.