# Why is the minimum value of a float 0?

Tags: c, floating-point

This code:

```
int main(){

    printf("The value of FLT_MAX is %.5f\n", FLT_MAX);
    printf("The value of FLT_MIN is %.5f\n", FLT_MIN);
    printf("A float takes %i bytes\n", sizeof(float));

    float fx = -1.24;
    printf("The value of fx is %f\n", fx);

}
```

returns:

```
The value of FLT_MAX is 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.00000
The value of FLT_MIN is 0.00000
A float takes 4 bytes
The value of fx is -1.240000
```

Is `float` unsigned or signed? Why is the `FLT_MIN` `0` but on the other hand I can store a negative value in a `float`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973737/why-are-flt-max-and-flt-min-not-positive-and-negative-infinity-and-what-is-thei

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits

Comment: Use `printf("%.e\n", FLT_MIN)`  `e`, not `f` to see significant digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `FLT_MIN` is implementation-defined, it's not zero, but a positive number (to be precise, it's the minimum normalized positive `float` number). One typical value of it is `1E-37`.

The problem in your code is, you are printing it with `%.5f`, only 5 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: @KorayTugay What output do you expect? Even `0.00001` is *much* bigger than `1E-37`.

Comment: I do not understand. My question is, if it is 1E-37 it is still greater than 0. But I was able to store a negative value in a float.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I see.. How can I print the defined minimal value?

Comment: @KorayTugay `FLT_MIN` is the name of the smallest positive normal number. There are more positive float numbers (denormals), and then there is zero, and then there is `-FLT_MAX`, the minimum finite floating-point value, and then there is -inf, which is actually the minimum floating-point value (but is not finite).

Comment: @YuHao the minimal positive normal value.  There are 2^23-1 denormal values between `FLT_MIN` and 0.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I see, thanks. I missed that..

Comment: @PascalCuoq I was confused because Head First C says this is the lowest value of a float: printf("The value of FLT_MIN is %.50f\n", FLT_MIN);