# typecasting of pointers in cpp

Tags: c++, floating-point, void-pointers, typecasting-operator

Can anybody tell me what's going on with the following code:

```
int compareX(const void* a, const void* b)  
 {  
    Point *p1 = (Point *)a, *p2 = (Point *)b;  
    return (p1->x - p2->x);  
 }
```

I have taken this code from geeks for geeks, **the closest pair of points**. can anyone explain to me the similar code in a much simpler and easy way with line by line explanation

also, I am unable to understand this piece of code as well:

```
float bruteForce(Point P[], int n)  
{  
    float min = FLT_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)  
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)  
            if (dist(P[i], P[j]) < min)  
                min = dist(P[i], P[j]);  
    return min;  
}
```

What's the use of `FLT_MAX`  here?

Comment: Refer to this for more details about FLT_MAX https://stackoverflow.com/a/7973772/14165412

Comment: Please only ask 1 question per posted question. See [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Comment: _geeks for geeks_  I've found that site to be have too much misinformation for my tastes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FLT_MAX** is a constant defined [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)
and the logic if used to find the Point with the lowest distance between all the pair of points in the array, the idea of setting the variable min with a FLT_MAX is to define a threshold limit value that can be exceeded by the 1st comparison of the 1st 2 Points...

Answer (score 1):

```
Point *p1 = (Point *)a, *p2 = (Point *)b;
```

This line is initialising two variables in the same line. Like

```
int a = 2, b = 3;
```

For pointers, the `*` is kept near the variable. The following will give you an `int *` and an `int`:

```
 int *a = nullptr, b = 2;
```

https://cdecl.org

---

> what's the use of FLT_MAX here?

Everything is smaller than `FLT_MAX`. So this is safe to check against in the first comparison for the minimum number.

Answer (score 1):

The `compareX` function in your first code snippet has the signature **required** if it is to be passed as the comparator in a call to the [standard `qsort()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) (or other, similar sorting routines provided by the Standard Library). The two pointer arguments *must* be given as `const void*` types.

However, when that function is used, the code will actually be passing pointers to `Point` objects, so the function must first *explicitly* cast them as such, so that they can be dereferenced in order to do the comparison of their respective `x` members.

Note: Although using "C-Style" casts will work here, many would frown on such usage. It is, perhaps, more in keeping with "Modern C++" to use `static_cast` operations:

```cpp
int compareX(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const Point *p1 = static_cast<const Point*>(a), *p2 = static_cast<const Point*>(b);
    return (p1->x - p2->x);
}
```